# How to kill image flash in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to use AngularJS built-in directives to achieve some simple JS effect without writing actual js code. It actually works pretty well, except the initial flash.

I know to deal with text, people should use `ng-bind` instead of `{{}}`

But how do you deal with directives like `ng-if`?

Here is my code:

```
<li ng-if="!magazines.resolved"> <!-- add "&& isOwner" when done -->
        <dl>
          <dt ng-model="changeToActivation" ng-init="changeToActivation=false" ng-mouseover="changeToActivation=true" ng-mouseleave="changeToActivation=false"><img ng-if="!changeToActivation" ng-src="<?php echo base_url('public/images/system_icons/add_magazine.jpg');?>">
          <img ng-click="addMagazine()" id="activated" ng-if="changeToActivation"  ng-src="<?php echo base_url('public/images/system_icons/add_magazine_activated.jpg');?>"></dt>
          <dd class="magazineName">Create <br> A new magazine</dd>
          <dd class="publishDate">Now!</dd>
        </dl>
      </li>
```

I know it gets a bit hard to read, but it's very easy. There is a model defined on `<dt></dt>` tag. If mouse is over this tag, the model value becomes true; when leaves, it becomes false.

Based on this boolean model value, one or the other image will be shown.

It works like a charm, but I can see both images at the very beginning, flashing!

How to deal with something like this then?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ngCloak may help, but you should also use ng-src for the actual image source, this will prevent your site from loading the image before the model has received a value.  Also when using ngCloak, you may need to load the AngularJS source at the top of your html file as it may try to load the image before it knows what to do with the ng-cloak directive.

Comment: Gee! That's very helpful! Since I also need to load jQuery...I actually put both jQuery and AngularJS at the very bottom...I'll move them to the top.

Comment: Will using ng-src and ng-cloak lazy load the image also if it has ng-hide applied?

Comment: I believe the image loading will still function the same with ng-hide, the ng-hide directive simply sets the css display property of the element to display: none!important

Answer (score 0):

Applying ngCloak to you `dt` should do the trick for you:  http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngCloak

Here's an example from the docs.  Note that it's added in two places- the directive as well as a class.  The class is only needed for IE7 support.

```
 <div id="template2" ng-cloak class="ng-cloak">{{ 'hello IE7' }}</div>
```

Comment: I added ng-cloack to my `<dt></dt>` tag. It's not working. I can still see image flashes.